I need help with my training routine please
I play basketball and i want to improve in these areas: athleticism (plyos), strength, mobility and endurance but i really have no idea on what days i should do what because im scared of overworking myself and doing more damage than good. I am flexible except for wednesday and friday where i have to do strength because i have set appointments. Thank you in advance. I have tried to google but i cant find anything.
